# How to get the user input from one class to another

Tags: java, input

I have the following code:

```
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("Enter a Numerator");
       int num =reader.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter a Denominator");
       int den =reader.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter a Numerator and a Denominator");
       Rational r = new Rational(num,den); 
       System.out.println(r.getRational() + " equals " +r.getDecimal());


    }
}

class Rational
{


    double getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }


    double getDen()
    {
        return den;
    }

    //getDecimal
    double getDecimal()
    {
        double r =  num/den; 
        return r;
    }


    String getRational()
    {
      return getNum()+"/"+getDen();
    }



      private int getGCF(int n1, int n2)
      {
          int rem = 0;
          int gcf = 0;
          do
          {
              rem = n1 % n2;
              if (rem == 0)
                gcf = n2;
              else
              {
                  n1 = n2;
                  n2 = rem;
              }
          }
          while (rem != 0);
          return gcf;
      }
}
```

The purpose of the code is let the user enter a numerator and denominator. Then the program will divide and give the answer to the equations. What I need help on, is I keep on getting an Error on the line of code reading : `Rational r = new Rational(num,den)`. I don't know why.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Looks like you need a constructor in the Rational class that takes in a num, den and calls set set functions in that class.

Comment: you have to read more on `Constructors, and access modifiers in JAVA`

Comment: The Error says constructor Rational in class Rational cannot be applied in given types.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a constructor in your `Rational`-Class. You try to initiate the Object with:

```
Rational r = new Rational(num,den);
```

But only have the standard COnstructor `Rational()`. To achieve that you can call this Constructor you have to add this construcotr:

```
private int num =0;
private int den =0;
public Rational(int unum, int uden){
  this.num = unum;
  this.den = uden;
}
```

Within your `Rational`-Class you have to use then `this.num`and `this.den`to get the the constructor setted objects.